# Python hash runtime

Tags: python, hash, runtime, execution

I have a runtime question.

In the Python function:

```
 def f(x):
     hash = { 1: g(x) }
     return hash[1]
```

when is g(x) actually executed? Is it when f(x) is called or when hash[1] is returned?

Comment: You could've easily checked this yourself by adding a few `print`s here and there. How hard is it to get your hands on a Python interpreter? http://ideone.com/NFJj8

Answer (score 3):

`g(x)` is executed when `f(x)` is called; `g(x)` is called when `hash` is made.

If you remove the return statement, you can see what's happening:

```
>>> def g(x):
...     print 'g(%s) called' % x
... 
>>> def f(x):
...     hash = { 1: g(x)}
... 
>>> f(1)
g(1) called
```

Answer (score 0):

agree with Matthew. More exactly, `g(x)` is executed when `hash` object is created in `f(x)`.